# No result from algorithm r.stats in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, algorithm, file-formats, modulenotfounderror

I don't understand why algorithm r.stats doesn't give me result in the sidepanel (show result); the error is 'impossible open the file'
What can I do to solve the problem?

I show you:

```
Versione di QGIS: 3.16.4-Hannover
Revisione codice QGIS: 654e76b3cb
Versione di Qt: 5.11.2
Versione di GDAL: 3.1.4
Versione di GEOS: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Versione di PROJ: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Algoritmo in esecuzione...
In avvio l'algoritmo 'r.stats' …
Parametri in ingresso:
{ '-1' : False, '-A' : False, '-C' : False, '-N' : False, '-a' : True, '-c' : False, '-g' : False, '-i' : False, '-l' : False, '-n' : False, '-p' : False, '-r' : False, '-x' : False, 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'html' : 'C:/Users/Nicolò/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html', 'input' : ['C:/Users/Nicolò/Desktop/NIK/UNIMI/3 ANNO/1 SEMESTRE/Idraulica ed idrologia/IDROLOGIA/12 9.12/Bacino Luvinate-Tinella/Dummy/HorizFlowDist.tif'], 'nsteps' : 10, 'null_value' : '*', 'separator' : 'space', 'sort' : 0 }

g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/Nicolò/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_fhmXKb/05bdfa9f5cde47598add5cb5b1b85455/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="C:\Users\Nicolò\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\12 9.12\Bacino Luvinate-Tinella\Dummy\HorizFlowDist.tif" band=1 output="rast_65d0ab6a2be3b4" --overwrite -o
g.region n=5079731.0 s=5076591.0 e=484671.0 w=480481.0 res=5.0
r.stats input=rast_65d0ab6a2be3b4 separator="space" null_value="*" nsteps=10 sort="asc" -a > "C:/Users/Nicolò/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html" --overwrite
Sto avviando GRASS GIS...
ATTENZIONE: Il locking concorrente del mapset non è supportato in Windows.
Eliminando i file temporanei...
Eseguendo <C:\Users\Nicolò\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_fhmXKb\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\Nicol•\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\9 25.11>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\Nicolò\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\9 25.11>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/NicolÃ²/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_fhmXKb/05bdfa9f5cde47598add5cb5b1b85455/crs.prj"
ERRORE: Impossibile aprire il file 'C:/Users/NicolÃ²/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_fhmXKb/05bdfa9f5cde47598add5cb5b1b85455/crs.prj' per la lettura
C:\Users\Nicolò\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\9 25.11>r.in.gdal input="C:\Users\NicolÃ²\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\12 9.12\Bacino Luvinate-Tinella\Dummy\HorizFlowDist.tif" band=1 output="rast_65d0ab6a2be3b4" --overwrite -o
La verifica della proiezione verrà ignorata
Importing raster map <rast_65d0ab6a2be3b4>...
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
C:\Users\Nicolò\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\9 25.11>g.region n=5079731.0 s=5076591.0 e=484671.0 w=480481.0 res=5.0
C:\Users\Nicolò\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\9 25.11>r.stats input=rast_65d0ab6a2be3b4 separator="space" null_value="*" nsteps=10 sort="asc" -a --overwrite 1>"C:/Users/NicolÃ²/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html"
Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
C:\Users\Nicolò\Desktop\NIK\UNIMI\3 ANNO\1 SEMESTRE\Idraulica ed idrologia\IDROLOGIA\9 25.11>exit
Esecuzione di <C:\Users\Nicolò\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_fhmXKb\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finita.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 456, in processAlgorithm
self.convertToHtml(self.fileOutputs[outName])
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 1059, in convertToHtml
with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Nicolò/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html'

Esecuzione fallita dopo 3.16 secondi

Caricamento layer
Algoritmo 'r.stats' terminato
L'algoritmo ha generato un file HTML.
Apri il visualizzatore risultati per vederlo.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this on another Windows user without special characters in its name?

The log says that it cannot find temp file *C:/Users/NicolÃ²/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_fhmXKb/05bdfa9f5cde47598add5cb5b1b85455/crs.prj* and the **ò** character could be causing trouble.